# Bootstrap 3 navbar collape width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Normally when a Bootstrap navbar collapses the resulting menu is the full width of the screen.  Is there any way to make it only as wide as the content and to the right of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in the following way--

**working example**

```css
 @media(max-width:767px){
              .navbar-inverse {
                width:50%;
                margin-left: 50%;
              }
            }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
           
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="nav-container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">header</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <a href="" class="btn navbar-btn" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
      <!--<a href="" ><button class="btn navbar-btn" id="stud">Studier demo</button></a>-->
      <a href="" ><button class="btn  navbar-btn" id="help">log-in</button></a>
      <!--<li class="diff"><a class="nav_list" href="testlogin.php">--><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>--> <!--Sign Up</a></li>-->
      <a href="" ><button class="btn  navbar-btn" id="friend">another</button></a>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Well that's an improvement but I was really hoping to have the menu only be as side as its content rather than 50% of the screen.  Anyway of doing that?

Comment: I tried using grid-system but without success. so for me you just have to customize width and margin-left according to the content width.